# Escolha aleatória de linhas em uma matriz no R

Tags: r, matriz

Tenho um problema que me produz uma matriz numérica mxn sendo m o número de observações (linha) e n o número de variáveis (coluna). Preciso escolher aleatoriamente p linhas (p < m), sem reposição, dessa matriz. Assim vou criar uma matriz p x n com a qual vou efetuar alguns cálculos.
Como posso fazer isso??

Comment: Não será antes "criar uma matriz px*n*"?

Comment: Correto, a matriz é de ordem p x n. Errei na digitação. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Para selecionar aleatoriamente `p` números de `m`, a maneira mais fácil é usar a função `sample`.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Faz os resultados reprodutíveis

m <- 7
mat <- matrix(rnorm(35), nrow = m)

p <- 4
inx <- sample(nrow(mat), p)
sub_mat <- mat[inx, ]
sub_mat
#           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#[1,] -1.2070657 -0.54663186  0.9594941 -0.4906859 -0.0151383
#[2,]  0.5060559 -0.77625389  2.4158352  0.5747557 -0.5012581
#[3,] -0.5747400  0.06445882  0.1340882 -1.0236557 -1.6290935
#[4,] -2.3456977 -0.47719270 -0.9111954 -0.6937202 -0.4755931
```

Comment: Funcionou, ótimo. Mas agora preciso de outra ajuda. Preciso fazer isso 20 vezes e guardar os resultados em uma matriz ou vetor. A resposta dos cálculos sai na forma de um sumário da seguinte maneira Model Chisquare =  80.84399   Df =  59 Pr(>Chisq) = 0.03107302
 Goodness-of-fit index =  0.8743683
 RMSEA index =  0.06115365   95% CI: (NA, 0.09736043)
 Bentler-Bonett NFI =  0.990771
 Bentler CFI =  0.9974839  Preciso guardar os resultados Chisquare, Goodness-of-fit index, RMSEA, NFI e CFI separadamente para uma análise futura e para determinar um Intervalo de Confiança usando Bootstrap

Comment: Para fazer isso 20 vezes, `inx_mat <- replicate(20, sample(nrow(mat), p))`. Quanto ao resto do comentário não percebi, mas parece ser outra pergunta. Faça outra pergunta com um link a esta pergunta, uma explicação dos cálculos e um exemplo da saída pretendida.

Comment: Usarei cada matriz criada da seguinte forma                      
library(sem)
cfa<-specifyModel(".......txt")
dados <- read.table("......txt", h=T) (485 observações)
p<-200
inx <- sample(nrow(dados), p)
dados_p <- dados[inx, ]
dataCor <- cov.wt(dados_p, wt = rep(1/nrow(dados_p),nrow(dados_p)), method = "ML", cor = TRUE)
dataCor<-as.matrix(dataCor[[1]])
cfaOut<-sem(cfa,dataCor,N=p, objective=objectiveGLS)
summary(cfaOut, conf.level=.95, fit.indices=c("GFI", "RMSEA", "NFI", "CFI")) Quero fazer isso 20 vezes (acho que aqui usa um 'if') e guardar os resultados do sumário separadamente.

Comment: É realmente melhor **fazer outra pergunta**. 1) Quanto aos dados, pode por o output de `dput(head(dados, 20))` na pergunta, que é a melhor maneira de termos um exemplo. 2) Na função `cov.wt` não vale a pena usar `wt = rep(1/nrow(x), nrow(x))` porque isso já é o valor por defeito. (Mas também não faz mal nenhum, é simplesmente desnecessário.)

Comment: O output pedido é muito grande e excede o número de caracteres disponível no comentário. Sou novo nesse fórum e ainda não aprendi a anexar um arquivo (se isso é possível?). Temos outra opção para envio dos valores? Sobre o segundo comentário, escrevi assim, pois é da forma que está no tutorial que segui, e portanto deixei, mesmo assim obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Não está a perceber, ***faça outra pergunta*** desta vez sobre covariâncias. E quanto ao outro comentário, o que eu quiz dizer é que quando um argumento de uma função R tem determinado valor por defeito não vale a pena repetir isso, pode-se chamar essa função omitindo esse argumento.

Comment: Acabo de fazer a pergunta que você pediu, segue o link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292014/como-executar-um-looping-no-r-e-guardar-os-resultados-de-um-sum%C3%A1rio-num-vetor