# Separar valores a partir de uma lista de sumários no R

Tags: array, r, matriz, summary

Da pergunta anterior [Como executar um looping no R e guardar os resultados de um sumário num vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292014/como-executar-um-looping-no-r-e-guardar-os-resultados-de-um-sum%C3%A1rio-num-vetor) tenho como resposta uma lista com 20 sumários com valores calculados a partir de um modelo especificado. Uma das respostas obtidas é da forma

```
 smry_list[[2]]

 Model Chisquare =  188.6337   Df =  59 Pr(>Chisq) = 1.797041e-15
 Goodness-of-fit index =  0.9272667
 RMSEA index =  0.07420728   95% CI: (0.06013725, 0.08844767)
 Bentler-Bonett NFI =  0.9916955 
 Bentler CFI =  0.9942733
```

Preciso separar os valores de RMSEA, GFI, NFI e CFI em vetores separados para efetuar uma análise de cada um. O algoritmo utilizado, com alterações propostas na resposta da pergunta citada acima, segue abaixo

```
library(sem)
cfa<-specifyModel("...................txt") 
dados <- read.table("...............txt", h=T)  # Amostra Original com 485 observações
p<-300  #Quantidade de observações retiradas aleatoriamente da amostra original
sem_smry <- function(dados, cfa, p)
{
  inx <- sample(nrow(dados), p)
  dados_p <- dados[inx, ]
  dataCor <- cov.wt(dados_p, method = c("ML"), cor = TRUE)
  dataCor <- as.matrix(dataCor[[1]])
  cfaOut <- sem(cfa, dataCor, N = p, objective = objectiveGLS)
  summary(cfaOut, conf.level = 0.95, fit.indices = c("GFI", "RMSEA", "NFI", "CFI"))
}
smry_list <- lapply(seq_len(20), function(i) sem_smry(dados, cfa, p))
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que isso pode ser feito com aplicações sucessivas de `lapply`. A função a aplicar é a função de extração `[[`.
No caso de `RMSEA`, nos meus testes deu uma matriz com 4 linhas, portanto tive de transformar a sua transposta em `data.frame` antes de criar a `data.frame` final.

```
RMSEA <- sapply(smry_list, `[[`, "RMSEA")
RMSEA_df <- as.data.frame(t(RMSEA))
names(RMSEA_df) <- sprintf("RMSEA_%02d", seq_len(ncol(RMSEA_df)))

GFI <- sapply(smry_list, `[[`, "GFI")
NFI <- sapply(smry_list, `[[`, "NFI")
CFI <- sapply(smry_list, `[[`, "CFI")

indices <- cbind(RMSEA_df, GFI, NFI, CFI)
```

Comment: Usei outro caminho que também funcionou                      
RMSEA<-c(1:20)
GFI<-c(1:20)
NFI<-c(1:20)
CFI<-c(1:20)

for(i in 1:20)
{
  RMSEA[i]<- smry_list[[i]][["RMSEA"]][1]
  NFI[i]<-smry_list[[i]][["NFI"]]
  GFI[i]<-smry_list[[i]][["GFI"]]
  CFI[i]<-smry_list[[i]][["CFI"]]
}

indices <- cbind(RMSEA, GFI, NFI, CFI)
print(indices)                                                                                        É claro que seu algoritmo é mais profissional. Muito obrigado por toda sua ajuda sem a qual não conseguiria alcançar meus objetivos. Até a próxima pergunta....